# How can i make my opencv wwebcam show footage faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I have made a program that automatically makes a window and shows webcam footage in it as soon as a camera is attached to the pc via a usb port. 
I made a version of the program with the `cv2.imshow()` function, however, this would take up to 5 seconds to make a window and show footage in it, I then assumed, by making a own costum window using tkinter, that the footage would faster show up, however this is not the case as the footage sill takes ~5 seconds to show. How can i make this significantly faster?

Heres some code:

```
from tkinter import *  # Import the tkinter module (For the Graphical User Interface)
import cv2  # Import the cv2 module for web camera footage
import PIL  # Import the pillow library for image configuration.
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  # Import the specifics for Image configuration.

print("[INFO] Imports done")

width, height = 800, 600  # Define The width and height widget for cap adjustment
RootGeometry = str(width) + "x" + str(height)  # Make a variable to adjust tkinter frame
print("[INFO] Geometries made")

ImageSource = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ImageSource)  # First VideoCapture
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
print("[INFO] Cap set")

root = Tk()
print("[INFO] Window made")

root.title("Main Window")
root.configure(background="white")
root.geometry(RootGeometry)
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = Label(root)
lmain.pack()
print("[INFO] Configuration of cap done.")


def ShowFrame():
    print("[INFO] Show frame Initialized.")
    ok, frame = cap.read()
    if ok:
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        print("[INFO] After 10 initializing")
        lmain.after(10, ShowFrame)
        print("[INFO] Showed image")

    else:
        lmain.after(10, CheckSource)


def CheckSource():
    print("[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.")
    if cap.open(ImageSource):
        print("[INFO] [DEBUG] if Ok initialized")
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            print("[WARNING] Exiting app after command")
        root.deiconify()
        ShowFrame()

    else:
        print("[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.")
        root.withdraw()
        lmain.after(10, CheckSource)


CheckSource()
root.mainloop()
print("[INFO] [DEBUG] Root.mainloop triggered")
```

Comment: How would i check that?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter creates extra overhead, so it will not make things faster. More likely slower. I've seen you ask a couple of questions about this and I got a little curious, so I wrote a quick sample myself. On my system it responds instantly. See if this works for you. If so, the problem is elsewhere in your code. If not, this might be caused by your hardware. The camera need to be registered by the OS before you can access it. So if either the pc, the camera or the OS is slow, this might cause your application to be slow.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    # create initial variable
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
            # if camera is active, then read and display frame
            # else retry to connect camera
            if cap.isOpened():
                    print('Camera connected. Reading frame.')
                    ret, frame = cap.read()
                    if ret:
                            cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
                    else:
                            print('Frame read failed.')
            else:
                print('Camera not connected. Retrying.')
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    

            # time to display frame and get input. 20 means max 50x/second
            x = cv2.waitKey(20)
            if x == ord('q'):
                    break

    # clean up resources
    cap.release()        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```